# Filesharing between OS X & Windows 10 on a htdocs directory?

Tags: macos, symfony, windows-10

I had a practical question for my own work at home. I want to use quad monitor for my coding and other work. I can do this with my macbook pro attached to external triple monitor. But it is not practical because of all the cable management and Macbook Pro is barely keeping up with the performance running it. So what I wanted to do was having my PC run triple monitor and my Macbook as forth screen. Code on my pc and share/update the files in the htdocs directory on my OS X. Like how FTP works.

I found this link: http://www.itworld.com/article/2844141/how-to-share-mac-os-x-yosemite-files-with-windows-10.html

But I'm not sure if I will face sudden obstacles in doing this with my htdocs directory or other directories where my work is stored and updated from time to time.(example:Symfony projects)

I hope I mentioned everything. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use one of the free cloud based, file-sharig service, like **Microsoft OneDrive, Google Drive or Dropbox**.

But files will not be updated immediately, you need to wait few seconds (in the best case scenario). So it might get frustrating quickly.

Also, from my experience, OneDrive on Mac is not the best choice when it comes to a Symfony project - it stops working after a while, probably because a lot of cache files, so I need to restart it and it's not usable at all.

Another solution might be using **a version control system (f.e. Git) - but you would be able to see the code changes only after a commi**t and push (and do it manually, of course).